# rake db:seed populate keys when seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I have state data in a txt file that I used to seed my States db which has columns :id and :name. the :name is the state 2-digit code. Used the following code in seeds.rb file:

```
State.delete_all
open("C:/Sites/rails_projects/sales_tracking/lib/assets/states.txt") do |states|
  states.read.each_line do |state|
  name = state
  State.create!(:name => name)
 end
end
```

I now have my Cities.txt file with data of city,state.  My cities db has columns :id, :name, :state_id.  :state_id is the foreign key from the states table.  What code do I need to add to the below part of my seeds.rb file to populate the :state_id while running rake db:seed on the city seed data ("code" is 2-digit state id).

```
City.delete_all
open("C:/Sites/rails_projects/sales_tracking/lib/assets/cities.txt") do |cities|
  cities.read.each_line do |city|
    name, code = city.chomp.split(",")
     ??
    City.create!(:name => name, :state_id => state_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dynamic finder to get the state:

```
City.create!(:name => name, :state => State.find_by_name(code))
```

Or if you'd like to avoid a few queries, and if the state code is guaranteed to exist, you can keep track of the states as you seed them in a hash and reuse them for the cities:

```
State.delete_all
City.delete_all

@states = {}

open("states.txt").read.each_line do |code|
  @states[code] = State.create!(:name => code)
end

open("cities.txt").read.each_line do |city|
  name, code = city.chomp.split(",")
  City.create!(:name => name, :state => @states[code])
end
```

Comment: This worked great!  The second option you presented was faster.  Thanks much.